# How to get workflow taskId in Alfresco process service using script task

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-webscripts

I wanted to get workflow taskId in a script task variable(Java Script/Groovy) and want's display it on user form.

Please let me know if you have any Idea regarding this.

we are using Alfresco process service 1.9 version

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you mean the task id of usertask before the script task?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala, That's correct, I want a task id of usertask, and I have to use it in a script task which I am taking before next level  user assignee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the taskId in a process variable using a *ExecutionListener. create a spring bean that implements the activiti Execution Listener, in the overriden method `notify(DelegateExecution execution)` set your variable like:

`execution.setVariable("your_var", your_var_value);`

In the Script Task you can access process variables using the Execution. e.g.:

`execution.getVariable("your_var");`

follow the [developer series](https://community.alfresco.com/community/bpm/blog/2016/11/16/activiti-enterprise-developer-series-process-and-task-listeners) for more details.

Comment: Can you please add some more details in our answer, please let me know how to store taskId in process variable.

Comment: not Sure if Script base task listeners (ScriptTaskListener/ScriptExecutionListeners) are still supported. https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#executionListeners